# Blurred images when the view is presented - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, image, presentviewcontroller

I am facing an issue regarding blurred images and I am using Swift 1.2. When I present a view controller, the images in the presented view controller look blurred. But when I push the same view controller with same images, then the images look good. Also, if I embed the image on a button, the images look good. Any idea why it is like this?

This is the menu with clear images,

[image]

And this is the menu with blurred images,

[image]

Comment: can you show some output

Comment: yeah sure.. will upload it now..

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have updated my post with original and blurred images.

Comment: @Deepika make sure your images are in top of viewcontrollers Document outlines.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. I should use `Debug View Hierarchy` for this know?